# How to correctly use filter_input_array on an array without keys?

Tags: php, arrays

I have in my `$_POST` array a variable without keys: (This is from an input form with `name[]`).

`var_dump($_POST)` looks like this:

```
array(2) {
  ["name1"]=>
  string(1) "ttt"
  ["name2"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "test"
  }
}
```

How can I correctly use `filter_input_array` on this array?

For example, I need use `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` to all `name2` elements.

**UPD**: `print_r` of `$_POST`:

```
Array
(
    [name1] => ttt
    [name2] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
        )
)
```

Comment: please use `print_r` and post the array elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$args = array(
'name1'   => SOME_FILTER // this is for example,

'name2'   => array(
                        'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                        'flags'  => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
                       ),

);
```

$myinputs = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $args);

var_dump($myinputs);
echo "\n";

Comment: I try to run this code: http://pastebin.com/rt1N4Kzv but first var_dump($myinputs) return NULL...

Comment: If I'm using FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY instead of FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR the code is working, thanks!

Comment: you need to send parameters with post request then get it with INPUT_POST

with define it can't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

suppose your post of `name2` is like this:`$_POST['name2']=array(0=>"100",1=>20,2=>"test");` then try the below code.

```
 <?php
$_POST['name2']=array(0=>"100",1=>20,2=>"test");
foreach($_POST['name2'] as $key=>$val){
if (!filter_var($val, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false) {
     echo("value is an integer<br>");
} else {
     echo("value is not an integer<br>");
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes, I use it now but can I use filter_input functions only without direct access to $_POST?